# Draw on the screen, C#

Tags: c#, graphics, directx

I seek a C# method that can print data on the screen 'externally'.
Basically, I have an DX9 application, and I want to 'paint on it.'.
I tried the `Graphics.FromHwnd(0);` method, but its flickering and its not as good as I want it to be.
I know theres a lot of application like Skype that can draw on the monitor, 'above' all other applications, but I can't understand how to do it programically.

I will be very greatful if you could help me.
Mark

Comment: You can only draw on a window.  It doesn't have to look like one.  It won't when you create one without borders and caption.  FormBorderStyle = None in Winforms for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a form whose

```
form.TopMost=true
```

You may want to create a transparent form so that the form itself is invisible.

You may even want to create a [non-rectangular form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984331%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes overriding the `OnBackgroundPaint` event will produce fewer flickers. You might want to try that.

Otherwise, I don't know what your code is doing to cause the flickers in the first place.